# Simple XML framework on android, class attribute

Tags: android, xml, class, simple-framework

Ive got a weird problem with simplexml framework on android. Im trying to read and fill an object called weatherdata from a xml source.

XML File (no control on this one):

```
<weatherdata>
    <product class="pointData">
        ....
    </product>
</weatherdata>
```

So my java file looks like :

```
@Root(name = "weatherdata", strict=false)
public class Weatherdata {

    @Element(name="product", required = true)
    protected ProductType product;
```

But I get a very weird error :

```
01-14 14:22:28.919: W/System.err(18011): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pointData in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

If i try to class=ProductType.class in the @Element field, it doesn't care. Even when I create the pointData class in my projet with a constructor, the error doesnt change. It looks like "class" as a reserved keyword mess with simple xml framework 2.6.2.

I can't change the xml. Any idea how I could solve that ? thanks ahead.

Comment: Is there a way to save all attributes on an XML element, then parse it later yourself. You'll have to read up on SimpleXML, and next time link it so we can as well ;-)

Comment: Oh I was thinking there was no need to link it since it's pretty well known. Anyway here it is : http://simple.sourceforge.net/. I already heavily studied it and made huge conversion of jaxb generated classes to simple xml. It went like a charm and I loved simpleXml for that. It's the first time I'm blocked on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using TreeStrategy to substitute the "class" for something else.

```
Strategy strategy = new TreeStrategy("clazz", "len"); // clazz substitute for class,
                                                      // and len for array lengths
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
```

Comment: Hey that looks interesting. Thnaks!