# Simple XML Framework and Android - strange class attribute

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I am trying to use the Simple XML library with Android and getting some errors with it (http://pastebin.com/7Nrk1esD), where the main error is this:

```
"org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader..."
```

The Model which has to be deserialized is also used by a rest-server to produce the necessary XML, there are also some JPA-annotations like the following:

```
@OneToMany
@ElementList(required = false)
private List<Substance> substances = new ArrayList<>();
```

this line produces the following xml output:

```
<substances class="org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList">
...
</substances>
```

Here I see now where the error is coming from - Android is not aware of org.eclipse.persistence!
But my question is now: Why is the line *class="...IndirectList"* produced and how can I change that to avoid the errors in the Android application?

PS: I am using simple 2.6.2

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862548/simple-xml-framework-on-android-class-attribute):

```
Strategy strategy = new TreeStrategy("clazz", "len");
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
```

But I use this snippet only in the Android-client to deserialize and NOT to serialize the model in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@OneToMany
@Path("substances")
@ElementList(required = false, inline=false)
private List<Substance> substances = new ArrayList<>();
```

This should work.